# Java read actual file type by reading first few bytes (Forensic)

Tags: java, computer-forensics

hello I need a way to read first four bytes of any file using Java.
Why the first four bytes? Because it's forensic thumb print of the actual file type (File extension not reliable as it can be falsified)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_carving

Now, reading a file this way (below, Java code) will read the file **"content"**, I think it skips file header information...? I can't get the *Magic Number* (first four bytes) and thus unable to identify/confirm the true file type of a given specimen.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("somwhere.in.the.dark");
if (is.read(buffer) != buffer.length) { 
    // do something 
}
is.close();
```

[Read First 4 Bytes of File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381880/read-first-4-bytes-of-file)

Suggestion please?

Comment: That is how you read the first 4 bytes of a file. There's no distinction between "header" and "content" for most files, and the "magic cookie" is part of the main content. It may read less than 4 bytes, e.g. if the file is shorter. What's not working? What behavior are you seeing that you are not expecting? Is the actual file spelled "somwhere" or "somewhere"?

Comment: Rather than doing this yourself you could use https://tika.apache.org/

Comment: Blank.  If someone upload an exe. But rename to xls. Can Tika detect it?

Comment: Thank you Blank.  I tested Tika. simple API call metadata.getProperty("Content-Type") gives me exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Blank suggested, https://tika.apache.org

Here's the code - in this example, **"test3_iamexe.txt"** is an **exe**cutable, with file extension renamed to "**txt**" by attacker.

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MediaType;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AbstractParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Property;

public class TestTika {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = null;
    InputStream stream = null;
        String contentType = null;

        try
        {
            file = new File("C:\\tmp\\test3_iamexe.txt");
            stream = new FileInputStream(file);

            AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
            BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

            try {
                // This step here is a little expensive
                parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }

            // metadata is a HashMap, you can loop over it see what you need. Alternatively, I think Content-Type is what you need
            contentType = metadata.get("Content-Type");

        } catch(...)
        {
            // handle it
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to use parser to get mime type, short version with tika defaults: `Tika tika = new Tika();  String mimeType = tika.detect(new File("C:\\tmp\\test3_iamexe.txt"));`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream is)
```

See here : [IOUtils.toByteArray](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29)
to convert your InputStream to a byteArray, then get the first 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the java.nio.file API for that; and specifically, write your own `FileTypeDetector`.

I happen to be doing exactly that in one of my projects:

https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more/tree/topic/filetypedetector

With this I am able to use `Files.probeContentType()` and return the exact type of the file as a MIME string.

See [the test file](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more/blob/topic/filetypedetector/src/test/java/com/github/fge/filesystem/ftd/FileTypeDetectorTest.java).

---

Now, how it works:

- you write your own implementation of a `FileTypeDetector` ([here](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more/blob/topic/filetypedetector/src/main/java/com/github/fge/filesystem/ftd/PngFileTypeDetector.java) is an example to detect PNG files);
- you make it return `null` if the detector can't determine the type;
- you register the implementation in `META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector` (see [here](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more/blob/topic/filetypedetector/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector));
- test it...
- and use `Files.probeContentType()`.

Comment: Files.probeContentType() is rubbish .. totally not cross platform see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407479/why-does-files-probecontenttype-return-null etc.

Comment: @blank sorry but if you say that, you don't understand how it works at all. See my implementations and the test files!

Comment: Sorry you need to implement for each type you want to check? csv, txt, xls, xlsx .. for example?

Comment: We've had this return null for some file types on Solaris in the last couple of months, it's broken. It may however be fixed in jdk8.

Comment: @blank and did you write your own file type detectors?

Comment: @user3761555 yes, or write one which can reliably detect several file types (for instance, txt and csv in one detector, xls and xlsx in another etc); the implementation provided by the JDK is no good in that it merely relies on file extensions, which are of course misleading

Comment: On a side note: Your PNG detector will fail if `in.read(buf)` will return less than `PNG_HEADER_SIZE` bytes, which is possible according to the documentation.

Comment: @xehpuk yes, I'm aware to this bug and intend to fix it -- not right now though, since I have other stuff to do. And I also know my zip detector to be broken.