# Reading first bytes from akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I'm trying to read the first 16 bytes from a `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[ByteString, Any]` and returning `[Array[Byte], Source[ByteString, Any]]`.

After reading the first 16 bytes, I want to stream the remaining `Source` as usual.

**Use case:**

The `Source[ByteString, Any]` is an encrypted stream, with the first 16 bytes in the stream being the initialization vector. I need to get the initialization vector to be able to decrypt the rest of the stream.

This is what I have tried:

```
Source.single(ByteString("This is my test string"))
      .prefixAndTail(16).runWith(Sink.head)
```

I would like something like this, however the `prefixAndTail` takes number of elements as input. **Number of elements is not number of bytes.**

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You can use take, to collect the first sixteen bytes right, and then use drop to drop the first sixteen bytes. ByteString is a collection of bytes, so it means if you take 16 elements from the source it means, you are collecting 16 bytes right?

Comment: @ShankarShastri Nope. 16 elements is not 16 bytes. U can to run: 
```Source.single(ByteString("hello world")).take(2).map { t =>
      println(t.utf8String)
    }.runWith(Sink.head)```
This will print the whole "hello world"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1. Since input source is coming from the network, some of the ByteString may be empty
2. We need the first 16 bytes to decrypt the rest of the stream correctly

I will leave some comments in the code as an explanation.

```
source
    .via(Flow[ByteString].map(d => {
      // Converts Source[ByteString] to Source[List[Byte]]
      d.toByteBuffer.array().toList
    }))
    // Source[List[Byte]] to Source[Byte]
    .mapConcat(identity)
    // Get the first 16 bytes from Source[Byte] and a stream of the remaining bytes Source[(Seq[byte], Source[Byte])
    .prefixAndTail(16)
    // Source[(Seq[byte], Source[Byte]) to Source[Source[(Seq[Byte], Array[Byte])]]
    .collect { case (key, source) =>      
      source.map(b => (key, Array(b)))
    }
    // Source[Source[(Seq[Byte], Array[Byte])]] to Source[(Seq[Byte], Array[Byte])]
    .flatMapConcat(identity)
    .runForeach {
      case (key, rest) =>
        println(s"${key.map(_.toChar).mkString} : ${rest.map(_.toChar).mkString}")
    }
```

An example of the test containing empty ByteString:

```
val source = Source(Iterable[ByteString](
    ByteString(""), // empty ByteString to imitate empty element from database stream
    ByteString("abcdefghijklmnop <- first 16 bytes"))
  )
```

Result expects `abcdefghijklmnop` as the first 16 bytes

```
abcdefghijklmnop :  
abcdefghijklmnop : <
abcdefghijklmnop : -
abcdefghijklmnop :  
abcdefghijklmnop : f
abcdefghijklmnop : i
abcdefghijklmnop : r
abcdefghijklmnop : s
abcdefghijklmnop : t
abcdefghijklmnop :  
abcdefghijklmnop : 1
abcdefghijklmnop : 6
abcdefghijklmnop :  
abcdefghijklmnop : b
abcdefghijklmnop : y
abcdefghijklmnop : t
abcdefghijklmnop : e
abcdefghijklmnop : s
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example makes a couple of assumptions about your use case:

- The first `ByteString` element in the `Source` always contains the 16-byte initialization vector (to which I'll refer here as the "key"). The remaining bytes (i.e., the bytes beyond the first 16) in the first element can be decrypted with the key. (For simplicity, this example considers the first three bytes to be the key.)
- The decrypted value is a `String`.

```scala
val b1 = ByteString.fromString("abcdef")
val b2 = ByteString.fromString("ghijkl")
val b3 = ByteString.fromString("mnopqr")
val b4 = ByteString.fromString("stuvwx")

val byteStringSource = Source(Vector(b1, b2, b3, b4))

// The first value in the tuple argument is the ByteString key, the second is
// the encrypted ByteString. Returns the original encrypted ByteString and the
// decrypted String as a Some (or None if the decryption fails).
def decrypt(keyAndEncrypted: (ByteString, ByteString)): (ByteString, Option[String]) = {
  // do fancy decryption stuff with the key
  (keyAndEncrypted._2, Option(keyAndEncrypted._2.utf8String.toUpperCase))
}

val decryptionFlow = Flow.fromFunction(decrypt)

val decryptedSource: Source[(ByteString, Option[String]), NotUsed] =
  byteStringSource
    .prefixAndTail(1)
    .map {
      case (prefix, tail) =>
        val (key, rest) = prefix.head.splitAt(3) // using head instead of headOption for simplicity
        (key, Source(Vector(rest)).concat(tail))
    }
    .collect { case (key, bSource) => bSource.map(b => (key, b)) }
    .flatMapConcat(identity)
    .via(decryptionFlow)

decryptedSource.runForeach {
  case (encrypted, decrypted) =>
    println((encrypted.utf8String, decrypted))
}
```

Running the above prints the following:

```scala
(def,Some(DEF))
(ghijkl,Some(GHIJKL))
(mnopqr,Some(MNOPQR))
(stuvwx,Some(STUVWX))
```

In this example I take the first three bytes of the first `ByteString` in the `Source` and use that as the key. The remaining three bytes in that initial `ByteString` are prefixed to the rest of the `Source` (the tail), then the resulting `Source` is transformed such that the key is coupled with every `ByteString` element. The `Source` is then flattened and decrypted through the `Flow`. The `Flow` returns both the original encrypted `ByteString` and an `Option[String]` that contains the decrypted value.

Hopefully this will at least give you some inspiration and ideas for your use case.

Comment: Thanks very much for you input! 

I think the problem with this is that since Source of stream will be an external database or file (in my case it's coming from Ceph), so the first element can be empty and is most often empty.

Answer (score 0):

Good old Java to the rescue:

```
val ivBytesBuffer = new Array[Byte](16)
val is = new FileInputStream(fileName)
is.read(ivBytesBuffer)

val source = StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => is)
decryptAes(source, keySpec, ivBytesBuffer)
```

as mentioned in [Read First 4 Bytes of File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381880/read-first-4-bytes-of-file)