# Streaming a Partial Http Response in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to stream only a few bytes from an Http request and then drop the request. All the requests responses are over 5MBs in size and I only require the initial 512 bytes of data to extract a field.

So far none of my searches have resulted in anything substantial so I have no idea where to begin?

The endpoint does not respect the Range header so that does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using `entity(as[Source[..]])` and then `take` or `limit` on the stream to consume only the relevant bytes?

Answer (score 0):

Would, sth like this work for you:

```
def readLeadingBytesFromLargeHttpResponse(response: HttpResponse) = {
  // Read first n bytes from stream, surprisingly difficult in akka streams
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822306/reading-first-bytes-from-akka-stream-scaladsl-source
  // Good old Java to the rescue
  val leadingBytes = new Array[Byte](512)
  val result = response.entity.dataBytes.runWith(
      StreamConverters.asInputStream(FiniteDuration(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    )
  result.read(leadingBytes)
  result.close()
  println(s"Bytes to process further: $leadingBytes")
  leadingBytes
}
```